# Android correct way to get File from Uri

Tags: android, file, pdf, path, uri

I pick a PDF from local archive using:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(new Intent().setType("application/pdf").setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT), getString(R.string.str_select_file)), request_id_archive);
```

and manage result:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int request_code, int result_code, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(request_code, result_code, data);

        if (request_code == request_id_archive && result_code == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri myuri = data.getData();
            String mypath = myuri.getPath();
            File myfile = new File(mypath);
            Log.d("mylog1", uri.toString());
            Log.d("mylog2", uri.getPath());
            Log.d("mylog3", f.getPath());
            Log.d("mylog4", f.toString());
            Log.d("mylog5", Boolean.toString(f.exists()));
        }
        else {...}
```

It seems that the file is not succesfully created.
Result of my Logs are:

- mylog1 -> content://media/external/file/7406
- mylog2 -> /external/file/7406
- mylog3 -> /external/file/7406
- mylog4 -> /external/file/7406
- mylog5 -> false

Method file.exist() return me that the file do not exist. Why?

In other code I try to manage the file for many other operations:

```
...
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
...
```

But my app crash ang in Logcat I see:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/20180702_121938.pdf (No such file or directory)
```

I'm testing my code on Android 7.

Comment: try this ` Intent intentPDF = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intentPDF.setType("application/pdf");
    intentPDF.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);`

Comment: Uri.getPath() does not give you a file system path. Moreover there is no correct way to get a File from such an uri. You are completely on the wrong way trying to do so.

Comment: `document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/20180702_121938.pdf` That is not a valid path. Try `/storage/emulated/0/Download/20180702_121938.pdf`.

Comment: @greenapps using your suggestion I workaround the problem removing 'document/raw:' using substring: uri.getPath().replace("document/raw:",""). It works. Anyway this is only a  workaround. As you said "You are completely on the wrong way trying to do so." So, what is the correct way to get the file from onActivityResult ?

Comment: You do not try to get a file. You use the url directly. You do not need a file.

Comment: Sorry, but I do understand why you say "You do not need a file". onActivityResult only return me a Uri. I need a File object to perform my operations...

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace **'document/raw'** with an **empty string**, so you need to add this code before accessing the file:

```
if(mypath.contains("document/raw:")){
    mypath = mypath.replace("/document/raw:","");
}
```

Comment: You saved me after 3 hours of debugging & searching.